# How to emit integers from certain range with some interval of time using rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

I'm using this but interval operator wants to be on observable object its not exist on range, is there a way to have observable that emit for example emit 60 integer with interval of 1 second, i have been doing this

```
 this.clock = Observable.range(1,60);
 this.clock = this.clock.interval(1000).map(function(value){
     console.log(value)
     return value;
 })
```

Its saying interval is not a function

also tried this:

```
 this.clock = Observable.range(1,60).interval(1000).map(function(value){
     console.log(value)
     return value;
 })
```

Comment: Do you want 60 integers from 0 to 59 during 60 seconds or do you want 60 integers during 60 seconds, with every integer as a random between some range ?

Comment: No just sequential from 1 to 60 with time interval of 1 second

Answer (score 6):

To have a sequence from 1 to 60 with time interval of 1 second :

```
Observable
  .interval(1000)
  .map(x => x + 1) // to start from 1 instead of 0
  .map(x => console.log(x)) // do some logic here
  .take(60)
  .subscribe();
```

The output here is :

```
1
2
3
.
.
.
58
59
60
```

**Here's a snippet that you can run to see the output :**

```js
// just to have the working demo on SO
let output = '';
let divToUpdate = document.getElementById('counter');

// observable
Rx.Observable
  .interval(1000)
  .map(x => x + 1) // to start from 1 instead of 0
  .map(x => {
    output = `${output}<br>${x}`;
    divToUpdate.innerHTML = output;
  })
  .take(60)
  .subscribe();
```

```html
<div id="counter"></div>

<script src="https://npmcdn.com/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.7/bundles/Rx.umd.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Angular2 :  [**`PLUNKER DEMO`**](http://plnkr.co/edit/GX7f61GzUsYZgt2ZpwRq?p=preview)

```
export class App {
  name:string;

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'

    let rangeObs = Observable.zip(
      Observable.range(0, 10), 
      Observable.interval(1000), 
      c => c);

    rangeObs.subscribe(i => this.name = i;);
  }
}
```

Comment: what is c by the way

Comment: `Observable.zip` calls the function callback `c => c` with values from each observable (i.e - range & interval in our case), but we only care about value of the `range observable` so instead of `(v1, v2) => v1 + v2` I just wrote shortest form of `fat arrow` function. Open [this link](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) and expand `Rxjs` section for more info

Comment: Sure, I dnt know why reactivex.io is not opening at my side, its something unicorn, i have a question what if we want to use rangeObs directly into view using interpolation and aync pipe?

Comment: I mean i want to skip subscription part

Comment: go ahead and just use async pipe, it should work just like that without `subscribe`, you only need to make it `class member` instead of `local scope variable`, so that you can access it in your `template`.

Comment: your answer is good but your zip is returning array even if with single but its array and i need only single value which should be not wrap in array, is there any way to parse/extract value from that array?

Answer (score 1):

```
var clock = Observable
              .interval(100)
              .take(60)
              .map(function(value){
                console.log(value)
                return value;
              });
```

Use take(count).

Comment: The Range operator emits a range of sequential integers, you are using interval after that, hence getting the error.